# Check different fields from an MySQL statement in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to see if the search text is in any of the fields of a table, but I need to add it onto a WHERE clause that's already there.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = 'test' AND email = 'test@email.com'
```

I need to add on the end of this extra clauses to check if:

```
AND name LIKE '%{$search_text}%' OR email LIKE '%{$search_text}%'
```

Can someone help me write this out properly?

Also, if there's a way using sql to check through all the fields of that table to see if the search text is anywhere in a row, that would be better.

Comment: Full Text Search would probably be a good idea.

Comment: not clear, what's the point of name\email being a known value and searched on, unless you meant OR not AND

Comment: Not sure what full text search means, and yes it's mysql

Comment: There is already a query running to get the data.  I need to extend it in the event that someone searches something.

Comment: but if name is "bob" addding  AND name like %% anything but bob will fail every time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for something like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE (name = 'test' AND
       email = 'test@email.com')
   OR (name LIKE '%{$search_text}%')
   OR (email LIKE '%{$search_text}%')
```

Searches that start with a wildcard, like the ones following the "OR" keyword, probably won't be able to use an index. Expect slow performance on large tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a simple condition to search all the fields in a mysql row. You can only do this using the like syntax.

```
OR (name LIKE '%text%' OR fullname LIKE '%text%' .. )
```